# How to use key-value state and checkpoints together?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As I understand key-value state interface allow to restore state after failure in my flow but can't restore state after re-deploy of flow.

If I want to restore state after re-deploy I should implement `Checkpointed` interface and save/restore state from/to key-value state use methods of `Checkpointed` interface (+ don't forget to create savepoint before deploy and run new flow with created savepoint). Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The state is checkpointed and restored correctly using either the `Checkpointed` interface for the local user instance state or the per-key state which you get via the `RuntimeContext`. Actually, using the per-key state is easier because you don't need to implement any checkpointing code.

If you want to explicitly stop your Flink job and resume it at a later point in time with the checkpointed state being restored, you can do that using [Savepoints](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/streaming/savepoints.html). Savepoints use the same mechanism as the continuous checkpointing which allows you to restart your job in case of a failure.